# Netty 4 ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter

Tags: netty

Which methods of class [ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter.html) will actually get called when this class has been instantiated and connected to a pipeline? obviously [messageReceived](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter.html#messageReceived%28io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext,%20I%29) is (as was the case in Netty 3). What about the other methods listed on its [documentation](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter.html#method_summary)?

Must an implementation override any of its other methods other than [messageReceived](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter.html#messageReceived%28io.netty.channel.ChannelHandlerContext,%20I%29) in order to process messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to override messageReceived to process messages. You "can" override others if you want some "special" handling.

Comment: Thanks. I think this should be documented more clearly, even if the only documentation is Javadoc. It's not as obvious as it can be browsing the Netty 4 Javadoc. IMHO.